# Recursive hierarchy (parents and children)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, recursive-query

I have a table that has a field with parent id. Children and parents are in one table. Example:

```
id | name | sub | status
```

I have to get all records with parents (parents and children separately). So, if i search category with id = 4, I would like to get record with id = 4 and record with id equal to the child sub and more.

Example:

```
id | name        | sub | status
-------------------------------
1  | Electronics | 0   | 1
2  | Sports      | 0   | 1
3  | TV          | 1   | 1
4  | LCD         | 3   | 1
```

So, I need exactly 3 record with ids: 4, 3 and 1 (with parents of parents).

My query is highly complicated, I have lots of join with others datas.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why you need is a recursive query, but MySQL does not them. You have four options: write a stored procedure, change your datamodel, do it in your application code or upgrade to a modern DBMS that supports recursive queries (basically any other DBMS)

Comment: Can not this be done with some JOINS?

Comment: I found this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce21a/1 but this is for given ID.

Comment: It *can* be done with joins, but only if you know th max. number of levels in your hierarchy.

Comment: So, the maximum level will be 4